# PHP chessboard 8x8 for loop

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, html-table

I'm trying to do a 8*8 chessboard in PHP with two for loops and I am getting stuck. Can someone help me?

```
echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        echo "<tr style= 'background-color: black;'>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr style='background-color: pink;'>";
    }
    for($y = 0; $y < 8; $y++){
        if($y % 2 ==0){
            echo "<td style= 'background-color: black;'>";
        }else{
            echo "<td style='background-color: pink;'>";
            }
        echo "10";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What is your current output and what would you expect?

Comment: Now i found that i cant style <td> .. i want to do classic chessboard 8x8 but there is no white color but pink color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0; $j < 8; $j++){
        if($i % 2 == 0){
            if($j % 2 == 0){
                echo '<td style="background-color: pink; width: 10px; height:10px"></td>';
            } else {
               echo '<td style="background-color: black; width: 10px; height:10px"></td>'; 
            }
        } else {
           if($j % 2 == 0){
                echo '<td style="background-color: black; width: 10px; height:10px"></td>';
            } else {
               echo '<td style="background-color: pink; width: 10px; height:10px"></td>'; 
            } 
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a clear problem description, I can only guess that the problem is that the rows are not alternating.

To add that - so that the first row starts with a different colour as the second - you can use the value of `$i` in the inner loop:

```
// let $y go from 0 - 8 and 1 - 9 in alternating rows
for($y = ($i % 2); $y < (($i % 2) + 8); $y++){
```

And you don't need to set the background colour of the rows, just the cells or - even better - just the alternating cells.

Comment: *but there is no white color but pink*  Seems we found what OP's problem is :D + your change. (And he could write everything a bit smaller: http://pastebin.com/AwS5gApJ )

Comment: @Rizier123 You've got to be kidding me, there is pink?!?! I wonder if that has something to do with `background-color: pink`...